# Do I have to tell the truth about leaving my job?

Tags: interviewing

I have been working in my current job for a month and am still in my probation period.

I don't feel secured here and am worried that I may get let go.

I started looking for another job.

If they ask me in one of the interviews about why I want to leave my existing employer after just a month, should I tell the truth or just come up with an excuse?

Comment: All you have to say is, *"I am looking for a permanent position for long term employment."* Don't say you are worried about being let go of. It looks bad for you as they'll wonder why.

Comment: Just say "it was not a good fit" (this is true).

Answer (score 12):

No, you don't have to, you probably will be asked though. But it might be a good idea to share anyway, hence it’s best if you developed a reasonable answer in advance. I've personally been in the same position, here is what I did:

I said I realized it was not a good fit, not what I looked for nor what I felt they needed. So the best option for both was to be honest, come forward and end it instead of dragging it out or staying for the sake of it.

This shows you are good at evaluating your skills and your fit in a company. And you are willing to take the right decisions.

Comment: You will be asked. It’s best if you have developed a reasonable answer in advance. Also practice actually saying the words aloud.

Comment: @JohnOglesby I added your suggestions to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

No one is hooking you up to a lie detector here. With that said, my answer here, as would be my approach to the interview in general, is to 'sell the best you'. So tell the truth but present it in a way that makes you look good.

So what are your reasons for thinking that you're about to get the axe? If you don't ask yourself that question, you'll be caught out when the interviewer inevitably asks the same.

If it is performance or culture related, you could say something like "I came to realise after a month that I wasn't a good fit for them/their corporate culture".

If it's redundancy or layoffs you are worried about, you can usually explain that as-is or you can say something like "I became concerned about the direction the company is taking with regards to my role".

Think about the real reason, then salesman/woman it up.

Answer (score 1):

The answer your question directly no you don't but remember that lies have a way of catching up to you.

> I don't feel secured here and worried that I may get let go.

That doesn't feel to me like something you should hide. I would literally just say that I doubt any company interviewing you should want to know more than that.

Answer (score -1):

It really depends on a few factors:

- Do you think honest feedback would be well-received?
- Do you think honest feedback would change things for those still there
- Can you express your reasoning in a reasonably civil and non provocative/emotional way?

If you can answer yes to all of those, then sure, go for it.  If you don't think they'll act on your feedback (and have good reason to think that) then there's probably no point.

If you're likely to want to go back to this place, say if the market changes, then you need to consider whether you'll offend the employer.  If the employer is pretty reasonable, then go for it, but if they aren't, consider whether or not to burn that bridge.

Comment: I think he’s asking about job interviews, not exit interviews. You’ve written a reasonable answer to a different question than the one that got asked.

Comment: DW, it's been downvoted by enough passing traffic anyway

Comment: Why not to delete "wrong" answer or rewrite a "right" one?